# Подскажите литературу по встраиваемым редакторам текста

Tags: книги

Где можно найти урок о том, как в сайт встроить редактор для добавления текста? Хотя бы такой же как здесь (при добавлении вопроса). Лучше конечно на подобии joomla.
[image]

И еще вопросик... Где скачать stemmer для utf-8?

Comment: Эм.. литературу/статью по чему? По тому, как реализовать такой редактор? Или тебе всё-таки нужен готовый редактор, а не литература? Описание, как использовать редактор у каждого из них и так есть.

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по словам **TinyICE**, **WYSIWYG**, **TinyEditor** и найдете ответ на свой вопрос.

Даже если покопаться в коде Joomla то там тоже его можно встретить

[вот вам ссылка](http://www.scriptiny.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/) на один из вариантов.